# Windows 8 HttpClient

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps, httpclient

I want to use TheMovieDb Api in a Windows Store app.

For Windows Phone 8, I used a WebClient :

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();

client.DownloadStringCompleted += client_DownloadStringCompleted;
client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=" + key + "&query=" + movieName));

private void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        RootObject resultat = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(e.Result);
        idMovie = resultat.results.FirstOrDefault().id.ToString();
    }
}
```

How can I do that in a Windows 8 app ?

I tried

```
HttpClient http = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
string response = await http.GetStringAsync("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=" + key + "&query=" + movieName);
return response;
```

But I get an error:

> Response status code does not indicate success : 406(Not Acceptable)

Thanks

**EDIT :**

Ok, I had to add

```
http.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("accept", "Application/JSON");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
var content = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie?api_key=" + key + "&query=" + movieNam);
return await Task.Run(() => JsonObject.Parse(content));
```

Three lines to do an asynchronous HTTP GET and parsing (not counting the try/catch you need to wrap this method with).

There are few resources where you can find out how to use `HttpClient`:

[HttpClient makes GET and POST very simple](http://www.jayway.com/2012/03/13/httpclient-makes-get-and-post-very-simple/)

[Microsoft' HttpClient sample for C++\C#\JS](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/HttpClient-sample-55700664)